# How to fix slackbot that is working for me, but when others try and use it, it does not post to there channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I am developing a simple Slack Bot to post in any channel(private,public,bot dms). I am using node.js,axios, and the chat.postMessage slack method (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
To post in my channels. The bot works perfectly for me, however when other people add the app/bot to their channels it wont post for them. The test users are all in the same workspace as well.  It still sees that they are calling it, however it does not post for them.

```
module.exports.result = function postMessage(message,ID){



  axios.post(url, 
          JSON.stringify(message),
      {headers: 
        {
          'Content-type': contentType,
        'Authorization': auth
    }})
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log("status: " + response.status + " status test:" + response.statusText +" ");
      return response.status;

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Comment: Are the other users testing in public or private channels? If its private channels which you are not a member of then your bot also does not have access to those channels (assuming the bot is using a token that you created). To verify this assumption let them test in public channels.

Comment: Is there a way to let the bot be apart of a private channel that I am not apart of? You are correct, it only works in private channels that I am apart of. Using my testing account i was not able to call the bot to post in a private channel I was not apart of. However it saw that it was being called from that private channel.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed the reason your bot is not working in some channels is that it can only see private channels that the user that installed the bot / the owner of the API token is also a member of. That is par of basic Slack security and can not be changed.

They are three common approached to solve this problem:

## A. slash command

If you bot is called with a slash command it will work in any channel and it can also respond to that call into the channel (either to the calling user only or the whole channel). You will not be able to use any channel related API methods though.

## B. bot user invite

Another common approach is to have a bot user with your app and ask the user to invite that bot user to every channel your app does not have access to. Once invited your app gets access to that channel through its bot user.

## C. Gather all user tokens

Or you can let your app gather user tokens from every user in a workspace. That way it can access every channel through those tokens. However, this approach circumvents Slack's security and requires support form all users. So most admins will probably not allow such an app.

In summary I would suggest approach A if you don't need to run API methods in the channel. Otherwise I would suggest approach B.